# Cannot use Json data from ajax response text

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am working with javascript to fetch data from a database using ajax. The response text is as follows:

```
{"task":"r","category":"s","duration":"0"}{"task":"read","category":"s","duration":"10"}{"task":"read","category":"o","duration":"10"}
```

I used `json_encode($data)` on the php script which fetches the data from the MySql database. How do I store the task, category and duration of the response text in separate variables. I cannot  use the response obtained. Here is the code:

```
 if (mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $tasks = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($tasks as $task){
        echo json_encode($task);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

```js
 get(url){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET',url,true)
    xhr.onload= function(){
        if (this.status===200){
            let data = this.responseText;
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: my guess is you are calling `echo` in a loop. Can only have one `echo` for whole JSON request. Put all rows in master array and echo that. Also provide a [mcve] if you want more help

Comment: The posted code contains multiple jsons. It should look like  {[ content_of_first_bracked, content_of_second_bracked,...]} or you have to add a devider text/sign and have to split inside of javascript and then jsondecode each part

Comment: Yes, I used echo in a loop. What should I used instead to get a correct response in the php script?

Comment: You should put all the results in an array, then encode that array after the loop is done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to declare the type of data received type with **dataType : "json"**

Like this:

```js
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:"php/page.php",
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data)
         {
            console.log(data);
         },
       error:function (data) {
             console.log("Error"+data)}
  });
```

Also your data should be a single json array and not a multiple json object

Try this:

```
$array = new Array();

$ c = 0;

while(condition){
  $array[$c] = your_c_object
  $c++;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

You should have a output like this on console.log

```
[{"task":"r","category":"s","duration":"0"}, 
{"task":"read","category":"s","duration":"10"}, 
{"task":"read","category":"o","duration":"10"}]
```

Comment: There's no need for the `$c` variable. Just use `$array[] =` to push onto the array.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, your response is not in the proper JSON format. Your response is in the format:

```
{"task":"r","category":"s","duration":"0"}{"task":"read","category":"s","duration":"10"}{"task":"read","category":"o","duration":"10"}
```

Whereas a valid JSON response should be in the format

```
[{"task":"r","category":"s","duration":"0"},{"task":"read","category":"s","duration":"10"},{"task":"read","category":"o","duration":"10"}]
```

Once this is in the proper format, decode the JSON by json_decode function and use the response in a loop.

See below example for proper decoding:

```
$str = '[{"task":"r","category":"s","duration":"0"},{"task":"read","category":"s","duration":"10"},{"task":"read","category":"o","duration":"10"}]';

$response = json_decode($str, true);

foreach ($response as $res) {
   echo $res['task'] . ' ==== ' . $res['category'] . ' ===== ' . $res['duration'];
}
```

Hope this helps.